# Problem with customising upload path for ImageField and FileField in Django 2.2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-decorators, higher-order-functions

I created a function outside the model to be used as a utility function that would work with any method by just passing a `path` string to it and it would return the file path plus a renamed filename. The `function(instance, filename)` that changes the filename is wrapped inside a wrapper function that would accept the `path` string.

Here is the function (stored in `helpers.py` in another app):

```py
def path_and_rename(path):
    """
    Returns wrapper func
    :param path: path string with slash at the end
    :return: func
    """
    def wrapper(instance, filename):
        """
        Returns a filename string, both
        and filename, with filename as an md5 string
        :param instance: model instance with the file_field or image_field
        :param filename: filename as uploaded (as received from the model)
        :return: str
        """
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]  # Preserve image file extension
        md5_file_name = f"{hashlib.md5(str(filename).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()}.{ext}"  # md5 from filename
        return f"{path}{md5_file_name}"
    return wrapper
```

And in my models i've done the following:

```py
image = ImageField(verbose_name=_("Product image"), upload_to=path_and_rename("products/images/"))
```

But this is producing an error upon `makemigrations`:

```py
'Could not find function %s in %s.\n' % (self.value.__name__, module_name)
ValueError: Could not find function wrapper in my_app_root.core.helpers.
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky. Django `makemigrations` command tries to generate migration files in a programmatic way.

When you pass a function to `upload_to` or `default` keyword argument of a model field, It imports whole module containing that function in migrations file. So in your case, Django will write following import on top of migration file it is going to generate.

```
import my_app_root.core.helpers
```

After that it will try to get reference of that function **by `__qualname__`** from imported module. Because in your case the function which will be ultimately used to get path is `wrapper` returned by another function, django will try to do `my_app_root.core.helpers.wrapper` which will be (and is) definitely failing.

So the ultimate solution is to use the module level function as a reference for `upload_to` argument. However, one a bit tricky (and may be ugly) solution can be assigning function call to a variable and assigning it a `__qualname__` with same name like this.

```
def path_and_rename(path):
    # all the functionality here


product_image_upload_path = path_and_rename('products/images/')
# assign it `__qualname__`
product_image_upload_path.__qualname__ = 'product_image_upload_path'
```

and then use this variable in model field like this.

```
image = ImageField(upload_to=product_image_upload_path)
```

Comment: When you said "_So the ultimate solution is to use the module level function as a reference for `upload_to` argument_" . What did you mean exactly?

Comment: Module level means something that can be imported from module. For example in your case `path_and_rename` is a module level function but `wrapper` function is not. The solution I posted is tricking django to think `product_image_upload_path` is a module level function.

Comment: So how am i to implement it in the model fields?